# Add-BindingRedirect not resolving NuGet vs issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nuget

So I am having a problem like I see other posters have had after using NuGet to install FluentNhibernate:

**ERROR**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.2001, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's 
manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80131040)
```

I saw that on stackOverflow answers and other blogs the answer was:

```
Add-BindingRedirect
```

However, this has not resolved my issue and all the results of running that command is:

```
PM> Add-BindingRedirect

Name                                     OldVersion                                                      NewVersion                                                     
----                                     ----------                                                      ----------                                                     
NHibernate                               0.0.0.0-3.0.0.4000                                              3.0.0.4000
```

When I am installing Fluent Nhibernate from NuGet, it says its dependencies are Nhibernate 3.0.0.2001 but it installs Nhibernate 3.0.0.4000

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I see that it adds the following section in the  node:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.4000" newVersion="3.0.0.4000" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

However, I still get the same error. Which just doesn't look right.  If Fluent is wanting 3.0.0.2001 and NHibernate 3.0.0.4000 was installed, this binding redirect, doesn't appear to me to be correct.

To be as specific as possible.  I just used NuGet to install Fluent Nhibernate in both my Web Project and a C# library project for tests.  Then ran a test using NUnit which continues to give me this error.

Comment: Are you adding the binding redirect to the right project?

Answer (score 1):

Add-BindingRedirect is the correct command to run, and the output you get is what's expected. After you run it, you should see some binding redirect entries in your web.config (or app.config). Can you confirm that?

That will then allow the assembly to be loaded even though FluentNH asks for an older build of NHibernate.

If that doesn't work for you, please include more details in your question about what you are doing. e.g. what is the complete sequence of steps that leads to seeing the error you report (starting with project creation).

Comment: So you see this error during NUnit but not in your web site? I think you need to create an nunit.exe.config and add the same binding redirect entries in order to affect the test run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a different package running [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) tests.

The solution for me was to manually add an `app.config` file to each web project with the same binding redirects as in the `Web.config` file.

The `Add-BindingRedirect` command had added the entries to the `Web.config` files correctly, but apparently the test runner evaluates only the generated `Bla.Bla.dll.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

sounds stupid but check in your source files and your packages sources and check there's no references to the old version there - if there is remove all version and re download the version you want via package manager console.

Edit: make sure you check all files because of how the referencing and binding works it can get very muddled and a reference in any of your files could cause the binding to redirect or still be getting the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my webservice was running but the BindingRedirect was not working for my tests.

The solution was to copy the configuration added by the Add-BindingRedirect command from my 'project'.config file to the machine.config file of the computer

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="3.3.1.4000" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000"  />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Once I copied that my tests started working